# Last values in the iteration are getting saved in python for

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to save a df to a csv from a for loop. It is saving only the last iteration values and not all.

```
df = pd.read_csv("final_Result.csv")
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for index in (df.loc[df['RFC_PREDICTEDFEATURE'] == 0]).index:
    print(df.loc[index-3:index-1])
df.to_csv('final.csv')
```

How do I do for this

```
zero_indexes = list(input_csv[input_csv['Feature'] == 0].index)
for each_zero_index in zero_indexes:
    df1 = input_csv.loc[each_zero_index - 3: each_zero_index]
```

can any one tell me how can I save this data in a csv ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving your results in a dataframe, that's why you are only saving you last result in your csv file:

```
df = pd.read_csv("final_Result.csv")
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for index in (df.loc[df['RFC_PREDICTEDFEATURE'] == 0]).index:
    df2 = df2.append(df.loc[index-3:index-1])
    print(df.loc[index-3:index-1])
df2.to_csv('final.csv')
```

for the second forloop:

```
zero_indexes = list(input_csv[input_csv['Feature'] == 0].index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for each_zero_index in zero_indexes:
    df1 = input_csv.loc[each_zero_index - 3: each_zero_index]
    df2 = df2.append(df1)
df2.to_csv('final_2.csv')
```

Comment: I added the answer for the second loop above

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your dataframe in the `for` loop:

```
df2 = df2.append(df.loc[index-3:index-1])
```